How to print the attribute titles and attribute values ​in product detail
In my Model Products have
public function attributeValues()
{
    return $this->hasMany(AttributesValues::class, 'product_id');
              
}

public function attributes()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Attributes::class, 'attribute_product_values', 'product_id', 'attribute_id')
      ->withPivot('attribute_value_id');
      
}

In my Model Attributes have
public function attributeValues() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(AttributesValues::class, 'attribute_id');
}

public function typeAttribute()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(TypeAttribute::class, 'type_atributte_id');
}

public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Products::class, 'attribute_product_values', 'attribute_id', 'product_id')
        ->withPivot('attribute_value_id');
        
}

In my Model AttributesValues
public function productAttribute()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Attributes::class, 'attribute_id');
}

In my Model TypeAttribute
public function attributes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Attributes::class, 'type_atributte_id');
}

My controller Product(show)
$product = Products::findOrFail($id);
return view('public.product', compact('product'));

In my product.blade have
@if ($product->attributes->isNotEmpty())
    <h2>Atributos:</h2>
    <ul>
        @foreach ($product->attributes as $attribute)
            {{ $attribute->typeAttribute->id }}
            <li>{{ $attribute->titulo }}:
                 @foreach ($attribute->attributeValues as $value)
                     {{ $value->valor }}
                     @if (!$loop->last), @endif
                 @endforeach
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif

But it is printing duplicate attribute title.
In a one product have Color: Rojo, Verde but printing all values color and duplicated:
Atributos:
3
Color: Rojo , Verde
3
Color: Rojo , Verde

In other product only have talla-Large and color-Rojo but printing all values color, talla and duplicated:
Atributos:
3
Color: Rojo , Verde
2
Talla: Small , Large


You should eager load the relationships to avoid unnecessary queries.
$product = Products::query()
    ->with(['attributes.attributeValues'])
    ->findOrFail($id);

$attribute->type_atributte_id should be the same as $attribute->typeAttribute->id since it's a BelongsTo relationship.
And then using the implode() collection method should be enough
@foreach ($product->attributes as $attribute)
  <li>
    <span>{{ $attribute->type_atributte_id }} </span>
    <span>{{ $attribute->titulo }}: </span>
    <span>{{ $attribute->attributeValues->implode('valor', ', ') }}</span>
  </li>
@endforeach

